# source .pam_environment file

Tags: environment-variables, pam

I'm using the `.pam_environment` file for some of my global environment settings, but whenever I make a change to the file, I need to log out and log back in again to see the changes since the syntax is different from normal shell scripts.

Is there any way to source this file like you would do with normal shell scripts like `.bashrc` etc?